# Given $f(x)=x^2-4x+3$, find the points on the curve $y=f(x)$ where the tangent to the curve passes through -6.

Tags: linear-algebra, problem-solving, tangent-line

Given $f(x)=x^2-4x+3$,  find the points on the curve $y=f(x)$ where the tangent to the curve passes through $(0,-6)$. State the equations of the tangents at these points.

Hi everyone,
I tried to find the points on curve but I'm stuck. I used the formula $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$ but I couldn't get an answer. Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks.

Comment: HINT : Derivative at (x,f(x)) =2x-4 and slope joining (0,-6) to (x,f(x)) is (f(x)+6)/x. These two must be equal...solve the quadratic.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

The equation of any straight line passing through $(0,-6),$

is $$\dfrac{y+6}{x-0}=m$$ where $m$ is the gradient

Now find the abscissa of the intersection(s) by replacing $y$ with $mx-6$

For tangency, the intersections must converge

Answer (score 0):

$$y+6=(2x-4)x$$
$$x^2-4x+3=2x^2-4x-6$$
$$9=x^2, x=\pm3$$
Therefore, the answer is both lines tangent to the point when $x=\pm3$.
$$y=2(x-3)\text{ and }y-24=-10(x+3)$$